# Sheaves of a variety X.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and $K = k(X).$ Let $P$ be a point in $X$ and $D$ be a divisor on $X$. For open $U\subseteq X,$ let $L_{D}(U)$ = {$f\in K : \nu_{P}(f) + n_{P}D \geq 0$}. I am trying to prove this is a sheaf. For this I am trying to show $L_{D}(U)$ is a ring. But I could not prove $L_{D}(U)$ is closed under multiplication. Thanks

Comment: Let $X=\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{C}}=Spec \mathbb{C}[x]$ then $K=k(x).$ Let $U=X\setminus\{0\}$ and take $f=1/x$ and $D=1.0$ the divisor containing the zero with coefficient $1.$ Then obviously $f \in L_D(U)$ but $f^2 \not \in L_D(U)$ which suggests that $L_D(U)$ is not a ring but you can show that it's an $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$-module. For proving that it's a sheaf just check the sheaf axioms.

Comment: @ Eshan M. Thank you very much. So, $L_{D}(U)$ has a group structure under addition. To prove sheaf axioms, the restriction map will be the module homomorphism. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct and to prove the group structure you should use the fact that $v_p(f+g)\geq \min \{v_p(f),v_p(g)\}$ for $f,g \in L_D(U).$

Comment: @ Eshan M, Thank you very much. It seems $L_{D}(U)$ is a presheaf obviously. This is what I am thinking to prove Sheaf. Let {$U_{i}$} be an open cover of $U$ open and $U\subseteq X.$ Let $res_{U_{i}U}(f) = 0,$ then $L_{U}\subseteq L_{U_{i}}$ implies $f = 0.$ Again, let $res_{U_{i}\cap U_{j}U_{i}}(f_{i}) = res_{U_{i}\cap U_{j}U_{J}}(f_{j}.$ I am not getting the idea how  to define $f\in L_{D}(U)$ such that $res_{U_{i}\cap U_{j}U_{i}}(f) = f_{i}$ for all $i.$ Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For $res_{U_{i}\cap U_{j},U_{i}}(f_{i}) = res_{U_{i}\cap U_{j},U_{j}}(f_{j}),$ define $f(p) = f_{i}(p)$ if $p\in U_{i}.$ Then $f\in L_{D}(U)$ since for all $p\in U,$ $\nu_{p}(f) + n_{p}D = \nu_{p}(f_{i}) + n_{p}D\geq 0$ if $p\in U_{i}$ and  $res_{U_{i},U}(f) = f_{i}$ for all $i$.This shows $L_{D}(U)$ is a sheaf.

Comment: Thanks @ Sharma Sharma, Is that $f\in L_{D}(U)$ ?